# RethinkDB: How to iterate over every single row in a table

Tags: rethinkdb

I am creating an ldapjs server to provide an LDAP interface to users stored in a ReactiveDB.  When a 3rd-party app performs an LDAP search for users, I want to iterate over all rows in a RethinkDB `users` table and send them in LDAP form.

According to the RethinkDB docs, `r.table('users').getAll()` will return nothing.

It seems like I might be able to do `r.table('users').filter(() => true)` but that would be a hack.

Is RethinkDB trying to discourage getting all rows?  Unfortunately that's just what I need so that OwnCloud can sync in all of the available users via its LDAP Auth Backend.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, simply using `r.table('users')` returns all documents in the table according to https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/table/.  Filtering options chained after `table()` are not required.